# Heritability of Student Loan Debt in Colorado

Tags: student-loan, inheritance

If a person does not pay his or her student loan debt off before he or she dies, what happens to that debt?

Answer (score 3):

Federal student loans (through the DoE) are [discharged](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/forgiveness-cancellation/death) (automatically cancelled) upon death of the borrower.

Private loans will depend on the terms of your loan with your lender. Some take the same approach as federal loans, but there is no standard and some will remain as debt with your estate.

Comment: It would be good to note that even if a debt is enforceable against an estate, recovery is limited to the assets of the estate. If the estate is exhausted, remaining debt is not "heritable" (OP's term) in the sense of passing as a liability to the heirs.